# Receiving [object Object],[object Object] [object Object],[object Object] values in LWC component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Here is my code where from LWC I am passing params to apex it then returned back to LWC but in the component it is showing [object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object]

//APEX

```
public with sharing class PosProductController {

@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
public static List<PriceBookEntry> getProducts(CustomWrapper filters){
    String response ='Check this out';
    String key ='';
    if (filters != null) {
        if (!String.isEmpty(filters.pricebookId)) {
            key = filters.pricebookId;
            system.debug('The key is');
            system.debug(key);
        }
    }
    List<PriceBookEntry> productList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    productList = [SELECT Product2.Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id =: key];
    system.debug(productList);

    return productList;
}
```

}

//Wrapper Class

```
public with sharing class CustomWrapper {
@AuraEnabled
public String searchKey {get; set;}
@AuraEnabled
public Decimal maxPrice {get; set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String pricebookId {get; set;}
```

}

//LWC

```
<template>
<p>Product List Component</p>
<template if:true={products.data}>
    <template for:each={products.data} for:item="product">
        <p key={product.Id}>{product.Id} {product.Name} {product.UnitPrice}</p>
    </template>
</template>
```

//JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { publish, subscribe, MessageContext, APPLICATION_SCOPE } from 'lightning/messageService';
import PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/ProductsFiltered__c';
import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/PosProductController.getProducts';

export default class ProductTileList extends LightningElement {

    filters = {};
    subscription;

    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    @wire(getProducts, { filters: '$filters' })
    products;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Subscribe to ProductsFiltered message
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE,
            (message) => this.handleFilterChange(message),
            { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
        );
        console.log(this.subscription);
    }
    handleFilterChange(message) {
        this.filters = { ...message.filters };
        //this.filters = message.filters.pricebookId;
        console.log('Handle Filter Change');
        console.log(this.filters);
    }
}
```

I dont know what I a doing wrong in the HTML. I have also refer the documentation it kind a same in that also

Comment: I suspect all is well and this is just the console log showing that you have objects. Try running this in the browser's javascript debugger and set a break point on where you log the data. You can then examine the data interactively to confirm that all is fine. You may see proxy objects, but again if you try to access the properties you expect you should see the values you expect.

Comment: Oh, and notice you dumped in "products.data" in each iteration of the product in your template, which I suspect isn't what you meant to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right Phl I dumped products.data in each iteration because the product name was not showing so I thought may be it was not getting the data from apex. But I checking whether the LWC component is receiving data or not

Comment: Hi Phil, I have updated my HTML file, could you please check it.It is giving me the Unit price and the ID of the product but why it is not giving me the product name

Comment: Surely that's just because you don't query the "Name" in `[SELECT Product2.Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id =: key]` (though you query the Product2.Name). Try changing your template to use `product.Product2.Name` instead of `product.Name`.

Comment: Thanku so much it worked. Now I am getting all that I wanted. How can I mark this comment as best answer?

Comment: Answer added to cover the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, your issue was that you could not see the product name. This is because your template is using:

```
<p key={product.Id}>{product.Id} {product.Name} {product.UnitPrice}</p>
```

However, the returned data from your Apex code actually includes the Product2.Name. To see this please update your template to:

```
<p key={product.Id}>{product.Id} {product.Product2.Name} {product.UnitPrice}</p>
```

NB: The ID in use here might also want to be the `product.Product2.Id`, but that's a different issue.

Comment: But Phil I can get the ID by this {product.Id}. But by the way. Thanks